# Barplot in 'R' showing something overlapped at text over the top of first bar

Tags: r

I have written a bar plot code in 'R' which is showing something wrong with the text printed on top of the first bar. Code and image are given below.

```
index_codon_norm_vec=c(10,20,30,5)
barplot(index_codon_norm_vec ,ylim=c(0, 33),space=c(rep(0,length(index_codon_norm_vec))), cex.names=0.6,mgp=c(2,.1,.2))
up_lim=index_codon_norm_vec+2
text(x=c(1:length(index_codon_norm_vec))-.5, y=up_lim, c(c(10,20,30,5),cex=0.1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You `labels` are not defined correctly and you include the `cex` parameter in the vector. Try this:

```
index_codon_norm_vec=c(10,20,30,5) 
barplot(index_codon_norm_vec ,ylim=c(0, 33),space=c(rep(0,length(index_codon_norm_vec))), cex.names=0.6,mgp=c(2,.1,.2)) 
up_lim=index_codon_norm_vec+2 
text(x=c(1:length(index_codon_norm_vec))-.5, y=up_lim, labels=c(10,20,30,5),cex= 0.5)
```